# Storing table of codes in a compressed file after Huffman compression and building tree for decompression from this table

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I was writing a program of Huffman compression using C++ but I faced with a problem of compressed file's structure. It needs to store some structure in my new file that can help me to decode this file. I decided to write a table of codes in the beginning of this file and then build a tree from this table to decode the next content, but I do not know in which way it is better to store the table (I mean I do not know structure of the table, I know how to write things in binary mode) and how to build the tree from this table. Sorry for my English. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with my question tell me by the future.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973123/storing-probability-table-during-text-compression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing a header in the compressed file with the sequence of characters according to their probability of appearing in the text. Or writing the letters followed by their probabilities. With that, you use the same process for building the tree for compressing and decompressing. As for how to build the tree itself, I suppose you'll have to do a little research and come back you if have problems.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to transmit the probabilities or the tree.  All the decoder needs is the number of bits assigned to each symbol, and a canonical way to assign the bit values to each symbol that is agreed to by both the encoder and decoder.  See [Canonical Huffman Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code).